# How To Run A Nifi Template As Part Of A DH Ingestion Flow

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

We have a nifi template that used to extract data from a relational SQL Server DB and ingest every row of the tables as documents in Marklogic.
Now we want to add DH in the mix, and run the nifi template as part of the ingestion flows to populate the staging DB.
What is the recommended approach to put the nifi template to be called as part of an ingestion flow?
Is there any other recommended approach to extract the data from the relational DB and ingested into Marklogic during an ingestion flow?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest integration here is to run your NiFi flow and use the PutMarkLogic processor to write data to ML - that processor can be found in the MarkLogic-NiFi connector at https://github.com/marklogic/nifi/releases . You can configure PutMarkLogic with a REST transform. You'll want to use the mlRunIngest transform documented at https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.4/tools/rest/rest-extensions.html so that you can reference your ingestion step configuration while writing data to ML.

Comment: Hi rjrudin, thanks much for your response! So to run the NiFi flow we need to run it outside of   a DH flow? we have our NiFi flow already writing to ML, so what would be the difference of having the put processor to call the REST transform rather than writing directly? is is the data provenance?

Comment: If you already have a NiFi flow that writes to ML using PutMarkLogic or PutMarkLogicRecord, you should configure that PutMarkLogic processor to use DHF's mlRunIngest REST transform, which will apply a DHF ingestion step against the data that you write. In that scenario, you aren't running a DHF flow via Gradle or the client JAR; you're referencing an ingestion step via your NiFi flow.

Comment: Note that mlRunIngest REST transform only runs the initial step of a flow, and it is expected to be an ingestion step.

Answer (score 1):

The NiFi community generally recommends that you replace Templates with [NiFi Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/registry.html) instead, which has versioning and deployment controls built in that are far more accessible than Templates.
Both Templates and Versioned Flows can be automated using the REST endpoints in NiFi & Registry, with variables recommended to be set using Parameter Contexts.
You can roll your own client for this, or you may wish to use my Python client [NiPyAPI](https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi).